# python django exporing excel server down

Tags: python, django, optimization

My website has a feature of exporting daily report in excel which may vary according to users. Due to some reason i can't consider redis or memcache. For each user the no of rows in db are around 2-5 lacks. when user call the export-to-excel feature it takes 5-10 minutes to export and till that website all resources(ram,cpu) are used in making that excel and that results site-down for 5 minutes and after 5 minutes everything work fine. I also chunked the the query result in small part for solving RAM issue it solves my 50 percent problem. is there is any other solution for CPU and RAM optimization?

sample code

```
def import_to_excel(request):
    order_list = Name.objects.all()
    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf8')
    default_style = xlwt.Style.default_style
    style = default_style
    fname = 'order_data'
    sheet = book.add_sheet(fname)
    row = -1
    for order in order_list:
        row+=1
        sheet.write(row, 1,order.first_name, style=style)
        sheet.write(row, 2,order.last_name, style=style)
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=order_data_pull.xls'
    book.save(response)
    return response
```

Comment: Not about RAM or CPU optimization(however it may show some differences).You can try using [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files) and also process your request asynchronously with [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).Streaming a file that takes a long time to generate you can avoid a load balancer dropping a connection and secondly async will process your request in the background and your server is free to process another request making it user friendly too.

Comment: thanks @KapilSachdev it works

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) , Accept and upvote :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instead of a `HttpResponse` use [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files)

> Streaming a file that takes a long time to generate you can avoid a load balancer dropping a connection that might have otherwise timed out while the server was generating the response.

- You can also process your request asynchronously using [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

Processing requests asynchronously will allow your server to accept any other request while the previous one is being processed by the worker in the background.

Thus your system will become more user friendly in that manner.